# own CryptoProvider for Windows 10

Tags: c++, cryptography, windows-10, cryptoapi, cng

I am required to make my own realization of the crypto algorithm and make it available for Windows applications. I made a crypto provider library for working through CryptoAPI under the instruction (in the article Service Provider Cookbook), except for the signature (Note: Starting with Windows 8, it is no longer a requirement that CSPs must be signed.). A library that exporting the required set of functions is in System32. Entries in the registry are done. The software in Windows 10 under which the CSP was developed hangs. But in Windows 7 when there was no signature this application produced an error.

Did I miss a step in registering CSP for Win 10 or what else could be the problem?

Comment: have you implemented all required exports for your `CSP` / `CNG`?

Comment: Yes. My dll exporting all required functions. Entries in registry are writen(in provider and provide type). Dll copied in System32. Did I miss something that i need to do?